# FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContextName() returning null in WildFly 10.0.0

Tags: jsf, wildfly-10, facescontext

I'm trying to get the relative address of my view via the function

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContextName()
```

It works fine in Payara 4.1, however, the same code in Wildfly 10.0.0 returns null.
Does anyone knows if Wildfly have some problem related to this?

Comment: What type of component are you trying that code snippet in?

Comment: I'm trying that in a controller. A function will process some data and return the action of a h:commandLink.

Comment: With a "controller" do you mean a managed bean or some other type of component.

Comment: By controller I mean a Managed Bean.

Comment: Are you by chance including the JSF libraries in your deployment? That should definitely work.